# r remove outliers from a data frame with two identifiers by ddply

Tags: r, plyr, outliers

First I should state that I am not terribly experienced with the R language. I have a large long format data frame, exemplified by the `df` below, with 3 columns: `Group`, `ID`, and `dat`. I would like to remove outliers (or rather substitute with the average value) within each "group-id".

```
Group = c("1","1","2","2","3","3","1","1","2","2","3","3","1","1","2","2","3","3","1","1","2","2","3","3")
ID = c("Eb","Eb","Eb","Eb","Eb","Eb","Sd","Sd","Sd","Sd","Sd","Sd","Re","Re","Re","Re","Re","Re","Tf","Tf","Tf","Tf","Tf","Tf")
dat = c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1010,11,12,13,1,2,3,-10000,5,6,4,3,2,7,6666,5)
df = data.frame(Group,ID,dat)
```

My base approach (which is NOT working) was as follows (I've tried several iterations of this code):

```
library(outliers)
library(plyr)
# Function to remove outliers
RmOurliFUN = function(x){
                rm.outlier(x$dat, fill = TRUE)
}
# splitting data based on first Group, and then ID to apply the outlier removal
GroupSplit = function(x){ddply(x,"ID",RmOurliFUN)}
df2 = ddply(df1, "Group", GroupSplit)
```

I get various error messages, but generally that the argument is not numeric or logical. I am pretty sure that I'm not appropriately calling the `dat` column in the nested>nested function.
How does one perform such an operation? I am open to any suggestions.

Comment: What is `class(df1$dat)` ? It sounds like you need to convert it to a numeric.

Comment: Agreed with Esther - if `Group` is categorical, it makes sense for it to be a factor or character class, but it looks like you're trying to detect numeric outliers. `2` is a numeric, `"2"` is a string, so your `dat` column is probably a factor or a character. Convert it to numeric with `df$dat = as.numeric(as.character(df$dat))` and try again.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I made a bad example data set, my actual data is numeric, but when I change this data set to numeric (I've done that above in the example now) it still doesn't work. Also `as.character()` and `as.numeric()` for `x$dat` doesn't solve the issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove outliers within each unique combination of `Group+ID`, you can add the function directly into the call to `ddply` and then reshape the results

```
library(outliers)
library(plyr)
library(reshape2)

#Make some new categories to have enough values for outlier detection
Group<-rep(c("a", "b"), each=12)
ID<-rep(c("c", "d"), each=6)
dat = c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1010,11,12,13,1,2,3,-10000,5,6,4,3,2,7,6666,5)
df1 = data.frame(Group,ID,dat)

df2<-ddply(df1, c("Group", "ID"), function(x) rm.outlier(x$dat, fill=TRUE))

#reshape and order the data
res<-melt(df2, id.vars=c("Group", "ID"), value.name = "dat")  
res<-arrange(res, Group, ID)[,-3]
```

Comment: Thank you Esther! Not only does it do exactly what I want, but it also eliminates the nested function! Leading to a much cleaner script. I am much obliged!